# Is there a way to get only month or only year from dateTime objects which are sent using json from database to javascript?

Tags: javascript, .net, json

I have a table containing 2 dateTime columns 'start date' and 'Endate' ,I have passed the entire table to javascript using json,the format of data which I get when I access a particular date in the json table is dd/mm/yyyy (along with the default time),I need to get only date i.e dd and only month i.e mm from this format in javascript

Is there a way to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Date: `the_string.split('/')[0]`

Month: `the_string.split('/')[1]`

Comment: var bits = the_string.split('/') then date: bits[0] and month bits[1] would avoid calling split twice.

Comment: I am a little confused as I am new to json,should I do something like this:
day=entireDateFromJson.spit('/')[0]?

Comment: No problem; happy to help. If you think that this answer is appropriate, feel free to accept the answer if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

you can use regex to parse the data.. let me know if you need help in this with your sample content.

Comment: You can, but regex is simply unnecessary for this task (splitting on a constant character). It'd probably run slower, too.

Comment: i was assume that is having some multiple content rather than just date content.. hence told to use RegEx.